# formatear numero a decimal jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo estos valores:

```
(string) 10.54
(string) 10.5
(string) 10.0
(string) 10.00
(string) 10
(int) 10.54
(int) 10.5
(int) 10.0
(int) 10.00
(int) 10
```

Deseo mostrarlo con el formato 10.00 (moneda peruana) por ejemplo si es:

- "10.5": Me muestre 10.50
- "10": Me muestre 10.00

En jQuery o Javascript.

De antemano, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta sería la función

```
function dev_formato_moneda_peruana(valor){
    return Number.parseFloat(valor).toFixed(2)
}
```

Solo fuerzas a que tenga dos decimales y usas la clase number para que aunque le

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed

Comment: perfecto, me sirvio. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Intl/NumberFormat):

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-PE', {
  style: 'decimal',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});

console.log(formatter.format(10.5));
console.log(formatter.format(10));
console.log(formatter.format("10.5"));
console.log(formatter.format("10"));
```